# Angular 8 - model in ngFor not updating

Tags: angular

I have an issue with Angular (8), I just can't figure it out. Hopefully someone can help.

In my template, I'm building a form, and to avoid repetition, I created an array of objects (there's many more):

```
this.countrySettingsFormFields = [
  {
    title: "Country admins",
    model: this.countryAdminsView,
    name: "countryAdmins",
    hasEditDialog: true,
    isCheckbox: false,
  },
  {
    title: "Sales admins",
    model: this.salesAdminsView,
    name: "salesAdmins",
    hasEditDialog: true,
    isCheckbox: false,
  },
  {
    title: "Product set",
    model: this.countrySettings.productSet,
    name: "countrySettingsProductSet",
    hasEditDialog: false,
    isCheckbox: false,
  },];
```

Then in the template, I am using *ngFor*, and passing the models from the array:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of countrySettingsFormFields">
<span>{{field.title}}</span>
<input *ngIf='!field.isCheckbox' class="col-sm-12" pInputText [(ngModel)]='field.model' [name]="field.name"
    [disabled]='field.hasEditDialog' />
<p-checkbox *ngIf='field.isCheckbox' name="field.name"
    ariaLabelledBy="availability-checkbox-label" [(ngModel)]="field.model" binary="true">
</p-checkbox>
<button *ngIf='field.hasEditDialog' type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Edit"
    class="p-button-info p-button p-component" (click)="editItemsDialog(field.name)"></button>
```

The problem is that when I first land on it, everything works fine. The models are bound, proper values are displayed.

But then, when I make changes to the models, the change does happen, and new values I entered do in fact get stored in the database, but the values in the DOM stay the same.

So after running this *editItemsDialog*, I

```
console.log(this.countryAdminsView)
```

and it shows the new value, but in my form it's still the old one.

I tried using trackBy, to no avail. Tried firing detectChanges(), nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Before using ngFor, I had all the form elements individually, and they were bound to the same models that are in the object now... I suspect it's something with ngFor, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Angular would update the DOM when it notices that the value has changed. However, with arrays, the "value" that is checked stays the same even when you add to it (`push`) or edit something in it (`arr[0].property = newValue`). (You can see this for yourself by defining an array as `const`, and these will all be legal)

The way to have it updated it to *assign* a new array to your field. So, in order to update your array, you could do something like

```
this.countrySettingsFormFields=this.countrySettingsFormFields.push(newValue)
```

or, if you have edited, follow the same concept.

The bottom line is, you need to **reassign it a new value**.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, @PMO1948!

In my update method I reassigned the value in the original array, and it works now.